# Laravel 9 Exception on tests and config:cache: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(): Argument #1 ($directory) cannot be empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am currently working on a Laravel REST Api. I wanted to write some tests but they fail after the second test-function due to the following error:

```php
RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(): Argument #1 ($directory) cannot be empty

  at C:\Users\matth\Projekte\Cookbook\api\vendor\symfony\finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:42
     38▕         if ($flags & (self::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME | self::CURRENT_AS_SELF)) {
     39▕             throw new \RuntimeException('This iterator only support returning current as fileinfo.');
     40▕         }
     41▕
  ➜  42▕         parent::__construct($path, $flags);
     43▕         $this->ignoreUnreadableDirs = $ignoreUnreadableDirs;
     44▕         $this->rootPath = $path;
     45▕         if ('/' !== \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR && !($flags & self::UNIX_PATHS)) {
     46▕             $this->directorySeparator = \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

  1   C:\Users\matth\Projekte\Cookbook\api\vendor\symfony\finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:42
      RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct("")

  2   C:\Users\matth\Projekte\Cookbook\api\vendor\symfony\finder\Finder.php:732
      Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct("")
```

When looking at the `laravel.log` I found the following:

```
[2022-07-18 12:56:58] local.ERROR: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(): Argument #1 ($directory) cannot be empty {"exception":"[object] (ValueError(code: 0): RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(): Argument #1 ($directory) cannot be empty at C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\symfony\\finder\\Iterator\\RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:42)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\symfony\\finder\\Iterator\\RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php(42): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('', 4096)
#1 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\symfony\\finder\\Finder.php(732): Symfony\\Component\\Finder\\Iterator\\RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('', 4096, false)
#2 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\symfony\\finder\\Finder.php(615): Symfony\\Component\\Finder\\Finder->searchInDirectory('')
#3 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration.php(88): Symfony\\Component\\Finder\\Finder->getIterator()
#4 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration.php(65): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->getConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#5 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository))
#6 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(239): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#7 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#8 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ConfigCacheCommand.php(101): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#9 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ConfigCacheCommand.php(71): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ConfigCacheCommand->getFreshConfiguration()
#10 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ConfigCacheCommand->handle()
#11 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#12 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#13 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#14 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#15 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#16 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Command\\Command.php(308): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#17 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#18 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(998): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#19 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(299): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ConfigCacheCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#20 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(171): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#21 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Application.php(102): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#22 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#23 C:\\Users\\matth\\Projekte\\Cookbook\\api\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#24 {main}
"}
```

When looking at the `api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration.php` file I found that the call to `$app->configPath()` returns sometimes a relative path, which does not seem to work. This is when it fails.

I replicated the same error when running `php artisan config:cache`. There the clearing works (with the full path to the config directory) but as soon as it starts reading the config again for the caching it receives a relative path to the config directory (`\config`) and fails.

I found some posts where they deleted the config directory, but this is not the case for me. Also the application starts without any problem (with `php artisan serve`). I also tried removing the `vendor` folder and reinstalling, which did not help.

If anyone has any idea on what could cause this please share it with me :)

The repository with the code can be found here:
https://github.com/m-thalmann/Cookbook/tree/develop/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have something to do with a key I've set in the `.env` file. The key `APP_BASE_PATH` seems to be used by Laravel and therefore overwrites. I found a reference to it in the `bootstrap\app.php` file. Renaming the key in the `.env` file solved the issue.